# Laravel signature validation failing on EC2 due to http/https inconsistency

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I've set up a new laravel app with email verification using the breeze starter kit. Everything works fine locally, but I am seeing some issues with http vs. https when I run the app on EC2 behind a load balancer. My understanding is that the load balancer is han

In particular, email verification fails due to a signature validation failure. My debugging has traced the problem to the fact that **the signature is generated using an https:// url but when it is verified the url is HTTP**.

I've tried http:// or https:// in my APP_URL config value

- Logging the request URL and finding that it is coming through as expected

How can I configure laravel to work correctly in this context?

Comment: It's not clear why the url is verified in http. If it's an issue caused by the load balancer then (if you haven't already done so) you will need to [trust proxies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

Comment: @apokryfos this was the fix thank you! I had run across this in another post but saw that it was built into laravel 10 and moved past it. Didn't realize that I had more configuration to do (setting proxy url). If you post this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a load balancer then the HTTPS request terminates at the load balancer and is forwarded over HTTP to the individual EC2 instance that will handle it.

In order for the end server to retain information about the original request the load balancer adds headers with information about the original request. Which headers are added depend on the Load balancer. Specifically AWS uses (among others) the [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) header.

Laravel does support reading in these headers and setting the request flags appropriately. This is done by setting up the [`TrustProxies`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) middleware

Here's an example setup (we use this at my work for an app in AWS so it does work for us):

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware {
    protected $proxies;

    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
}
```

This middleware is included by default in the Laravel boilerplate `Kernel.php` file.

The reasons why this needs manual configuration is:

1. Each different proxy may set different headers
2. Proxies do not unset headers that are sent with the request so reading all of them may result in users spoofing some headers and tricking your webserver to e.g. use the wrong host or protocol in a response